# Access harddisk from Ubuntu Customization Kit-prompt

Tags: live-cd, customization, custom-installer

How do I access my hard disk from the Ubuntu Customization Kit-prompt?

The mounted file system is the Live CD's own system. I want to use it for installation of deb-packages stored at the local hard disk.